# Is there a way to have regular expression in ~/.ssh/config

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have two set of server. Test on production. 
All server have internal ip. 
currently I am using alias to login:

```
Host pro-10
Hostname 192.168.1.10
ProxyCommand ssh production-server nc %h %p
```

For every server I need to repeat this rule. I am looking for a regualr expression way for doing this ?

```
Host pro-*
Hostname 192.168.1.$1
ProxyCommand ssh production-server nc %h %p
```

Is there a way of doing this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, ssh doesn't support regular expression in [`ssh_config (1)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) and the example you gave aren't regular expressions. [`ssh_config (1)`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) supports `PATTERNS`, i.e. you can define a pattern for your IPs, i.e:

```
Host 192.168.1.*
  ProxyCommand ssh production-server nc %h %p
```

and you should be able to have forwarding for all your internal IPs. Another solution would be to add entries to `/etc/hosts` for the specific IPs, i.e:

```
192.168.1.10 pro10
192.168.1.11 pro11
```

and create one entry in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host pro1?
  ProxyCommand ssh production-server nc %h %p
```

Comment: thanks for answer. Pattern will not work for me as it is internal ip, so Ip b/s test and production system will be getting conflicted.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible unfortunately. As you probably already know you can use the `%h` expansion, but that's about it.

In your case why not use a `for` loop?

```
for i in {4..10}
do  
  echo -e "Host pro-$i\nHostname 192.168.1.$i\nProxyCommand ssh production-server nc %h %p\n"; >> ~/.ssh/config
done
```

The only other option I could come up with is, maybe create DNS entries with regexp, if your server supports this and then use those.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that a regular expression is possible to dynamically set up the SSH configuration.  However, you should be able to use a for loop in Bash to automatically create the three lines in the config file for each server.  For this example, I will assume you need to create entries for servers pro-75 to pro-125.

```
for i in $(seq 75 125);
do
    echo "Host pro-$i" >> ~/.ssh/config
    echo "Hostname 192.168.1.$i" >> ~/.ssh/config
    echo "ProxyCommand ssh production-server nc %h %p" >> ~/.ssh/config
    echo "\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
done
```

This will build a list of all numbers from 75 to 125 and store that as the list for the loop.  It then loops through each member of the list and replaces $i. Each line is appended to the end of the SSH user config file.  Finally, I included the newline to break up the configuration file just a little bit.

If you have specific values which are needed on the list, rather than a contiguous segment of numbers, then build a list manually, like this:

```
1 23 45 67 89
```

Answer (score 0):

with ProxyCommand its possible - because its just a set of shell commands:

Host pro-*
ProxyCommand ssh production-server nc 192.168.1.`echo "%h" | perl -pe 's/pro-//'` %p