# Regexp in .ssh/config

Tags: ssh, regular-expression

At work, I often have to log into hosts which follow a common naming scheme, e.g. `qc01` - `qc12`, `hc01` - `hc10`, and so on. All of these need to get the same config values in my laptop's `.ssh/config`. Of course, I could use entries for the hosts `qc*` and `hc*`, but I'm wondering if instead it is somehow possible to use regular expressions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [gelraen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3886/gelraen) stated default `ssh_config` won't support regular expressions but you can try something different like :

- [Advanced ssh-config on Github](https://github.com/moul/advanced-ssh-config) - it is said to have better regex engine but you have to test it on your own
- some workarounds : [another question on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60400/is-there-a-way-to-have-regular-expression-in-ssh-config)

Answer (score 10):

You can use full regular expressions in your `ssh_config`.

The relevant documentation is IMO very hard to read and understand. I only understand it because I have 13+ years Linux experience and and 8+ years using `ssh`. So here is my summary of the documentation:

- `man ssh_config` describes a feature called `Match`
- then there is a feature called `exec` which let's you use an arbitrary shell command for determining a match
- passing input parameters to the arbitrary shell command is possible and described in the section labeled `TOKENS`

**In my case i ended up using in my `~/.ssh/config`**:

```
Match exec "echo %h | grep -q 'NAME[0-9]\+$'"
    User USER
    IdentityFile /path/to/identity/file
    Hostname %h.fully.qualified.domain.name
```

**Testing must be done with something tricky like this. And to do that testing you call `ssh -vvv HOSTNAME`. Which will show exactly what is happening, and whether your new `Match` is implemented correctly.**

Answer (score 5):

Please, see `PATTERNS` section in `man ssh_config`.

Long answer is:
No, you can't, unless you patch your `ssh` to support that.

Comment: I cannot find this section in my `man ssh_config`.

Comment: try http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config

Comment: What version did that appear?

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer from Trevor:

More complex hosts are also possible, like matching `foo123.123` and `foo10.10` in one rule **WITHOUT** having DNS entries for the used hostnames:

```
Match exec "echo %h | grep -q 'foo[0-9]\+.[0-9]\+$'"
    Port 1234 # just to show it can be paired with non-default ports too,
              # see %p in man ssh_config
    ProxyCommand /usr/bin/nc 10.10.$(echo %h | sed -e 's/foo//') %p
```

Using the ProxyCommand to *manipulate* the content of %h with the shell and connecting to the right port through a netcat.
This way you can create *presets* for category of hosts, without creating individual entries.

Comment: This looks great, but I can't get it to work. I specified the port as fixed (22),  but ssh -vvv gets stuck on "debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.1" for a while and then prints "kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host". Any pointers? :)